# Clicking links with certain characters using power automate

Tags: scripting, rpa, power-automate-desktop

I am trying to create a desktop flow that clicks links with only specific characters "WO". I'm having a hard time doing it in power automate. I easily did it with the re module in python.

Would anyone help me on a detailed process on how to do it on power automate? Thanks

I attempted to do it by extracting web data and obtained it as a web data table. I tried doing a python script injection but to no avail.

Comment: Is it possible to add a bit more information around the links, are there multiple ones with the WO as part of the id?, name? href? eg. WO-1 123_WO?

Comment: also it sounds like something along the lines of the following answer might help. Not exactly that answer but along the lines 
 of using the html selectors to find the links, without more detail in your question it is difficult to know what you are are aiming for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74006904/loop-through-drop-down-with-dynamic-html-table/74682020#74682020

Comment: Please add in your question what have you tried or researched.